# multitail regex not working

Tags: command-line, regex, tail

I am trying to use multitail to colorize some log files for a program I have written. I've created my own `colorscheme` within `/etc/multitail.conf` and I am able to colorize a very simple regex that matches to a single word. However, I cannot get a more complex regex to work:

```
(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d+[Zz]?)
```

This regex is supposed to match ISO date strings returned from a Javascript Date.toISOString() call. When testing this regex on multiple sites (regexp.com, regextester.com), it does indeed match the timestamps in my log files. Yet when I run `multitail -cS express /my/log/file`, the simple word regex works but not the timestamps.

Here the relevant section of my `/etc/multitail.conf` file:

```
# express-proxy logs
colorscheme:express:express-proxy log files
cs_re:red:(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d+[Zz]?) # This does not
cs_re:yellow:Headers # This works fine
```

Why won't it recognize my valid regex? Do I need to somehow escape a value or two?

multitail v6.4.2, Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2

An example log file:

```
2022-06-10T11:46:55.608Z | info | Incoming Request:
        Client Address: ::1
        Target-URL:     https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v5/namespace/ns:url/name/JohnLCarveth
        method:         GET
        Request Body:   {}
        Headers:        {"target-url":"https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v5/namespace/ns:url/name/JohnLCarveth","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.29.0","accept":"*/*","postman-token":"e680d0ad-a9c9-4348-a3ea-dede02a043e6","host":"localhost:3069","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","connection":"keep-alive"}
2022-06-10T11:46:55.783Z | info | Request Response
Status Code:    200
Elapsed Time:   175.78ms
Response Body:  ["33ceb1c7-8ece-530f-b53a-006f4a32348f"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex is correct but the `\d` sign is not recognized by `multitail`.
Replacing `\d` by `[0-9]` should work.

(PS: don't know why exactly `\d` is not recognized. This happened in other programs. Someone knows?)

Comment: This worked! Interesting, thank you for the info

Comment: `\d` isn't [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), you might see it in tools which support  a Perl-like RE (e.g., `grep -P` will understand `\d`, but plain `grep` (BRE) or `grep -E` (ERE) won't). The standard is the character class `[:digit:]`, you can do `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[0-9]`.